# how to connect to the internet on my android application while i have a server with a proxy "IP:Port" and asks for a username and password

Tags: android, internet-connection, proxy-server

I am developing an application on android, and there is a proxy server in the company preventing it from accessing the internet.
I recall there are Http methods in java that serves the purpose, I searched for them but with no result.

So what I'd like is how to put the server IP-address and port-number, with my login-username and password, and the domain-name.

Note: I have set my emulator to connect to the internet by going to the APNs and it successfully connects to the internet via the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the following code

```
/**
 * A simple example that uses HttpClient to execute an HTTP request
 * over a secure connection tunneled through an authenticating proxy.
 */
public class ClientProxyAuthentication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("localhost", 8080),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

            HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("www.verisign.com", 443, "https");
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");

            System.out.println("executing request: " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            System.out.println("via proxy: " + proxy);
            System.out.println("to target: " + targetHost);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: worked! Thank you :)! Thank you :)! Thank you :)!!! you helped me a lottttt thankss!!